# Integral: Area of figure described in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Lets say we have a figure described as follows:

$r=2\cdot\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$

Click here to see a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%20%3D%202*sqrt%28cos%282*phi%29%29).

Now lets say that we want to calculate the area of this rotated eight.

I'd like to understand what has to be done in order to integrate in polar coordinates.

So far I've noticed, that the following integral is wrong:

$4 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} r \ dr$

And I've found that the following integral would lead to the correct result:

$4 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{2} r^2 \ dr$

However, I don't know how this formula for the correct integral can be derived. What is the process of getting to the correct formula? Does this relate to the functional-determinant, volume-element of coordinate transforms or multidimensional integrals in some way?

Comment: See https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Calculus/Section_9.4--Areas_and_Lengths_in_Polar_Coordinates/Areas_and_Lengths_in_Polar_Coordinates.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this useful document! Now I see how this comes from the Riemann sums. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad you found this useful.  (MSE discourages answers which are simply links.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, the curve: $\ r=2\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ is symmetrical about x-axis & y-axis

area bounded by the curve $\ r=2\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ is  $$2\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta $$ $$=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}r^2d\theta $$
$$=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}4(\cos2\theta)d\theta $$ 
$$=8\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos2\theta d\theta $$ $$=8\left[\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}\right]_{0}^{\pi/4}$$ $$=8\left[\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{2}}{2}-0\right]$$ $$=8\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]=4$$

Comment: Thanks for calculating it. However, it doesn't answer my question. I wanted to know where the formula for the area of a region whose boundary is given by a polar equation comes from. I could calculate the integral, but I did not understand why we're using $\int_a^b \frac{1}{2} r^2 \ d\phi$ with polar coordinates.

Comment: Alright, notice the area of the sector with a radius $r$ subtending an small angle $d\theta$ is $$=\frac{1}{2}\text{(radius)}^2\times\text{(aperture angle)}=\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta$$